# JEvents change "Latest Event"-Module align

Tags: component, jevents

Is there a way to change the alignment of the latest events of JEvents to horizontal instead of vertical?

Maybe in the `div class="jeventslatest"`?

This should be vertical aligned.

[image: Jevents]

Comment: What layout is this? A component layout or a module one?

Comment: Module- changed the title properly

Comment: Is this similar to your list events http://activities.jeventsdemo.net/ If not, could you post a link to a live demo?

Comment: Applying `float: left` will do the trick in general, but we need to see live demo to be more specific.

Comment: worked @ Dmitry Rekun plz add to answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a module class suffix to the module and then add your own styling in your template. 
Have to actually see the code in order to tell you what styling to add/override.